# What is the difference between metrics.auc and scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: python, excel, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am getting different values when I calculate the Area Under the Curve when use sklearn.metrics.auc and when I use scipy.integrate.quad.

To calculate the AUC, I passing in my data:

```
auc_path = metrics.auc(path,year)
auc_sbt = metrics.auc(sbt,year)

auc_path = 14929608030
auc_sbt = 14846098649
```

To calculate the definite integral, I input the trendline equations (generated from the same data I input above) that I found from Excel into python:

```
def cur_path(x):
    return -47177.249*x + 8586190.275
cur_path_i, cur_path_err = quad(cur_path,1,23)

def req_path(x):
    return 23195385.6616*np.exp(-0.049*x) 
req_path_i, req_path_err = quad(req_path,24,61)

def sbt(x):
    return 8838484.57*np.exp(-0.03*x) 
sbt_i, sbt_err = quad(sbt,1,61)

path = 298653886
sbt = 238648501
```

Is the error attributed to the trendline equation from Excel?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain how cur_path_i and req_path_i relate to path? Also is your dataset small enough to post it? Currently, we don't have enough information solve your problem.

Comment: you can think of 'path' as a piecewise function. 'cur_path_i' and 'req_path_i' are the two pieces. 'cur_path_i' is defined by a linear equation and 'req_path_i' is defined by an exponential equation.

Comment: data is very easy to recreate. for the 'sbt' list, start with 8549826. for all the following values, simply multiply the previous value by 0.96734. So you will have an array of 61 elements that looks like [8549826, 8270595, 8000483, 7739193...1205441, 1166072]

Comment: for cur_path_i: follow the same procedure...start at 8549826, and multiply by 0.9941. [8549826, 8499665...7556006, 7511675]

Comment: for req_path_i: follow the same procedure...start at 7511675, and multiply by 0.9522. [7511675, 7152321...1224659, 1166072]

Comment: finally, the 'year' array is [1990...2050]. However, to do the integration calc in python, you need to use [1...61]. The cur_path_i function goes from [1, 23], and the req_path_i function goes from [24,61]. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Those are essential details. Could you please edit your question to include some code for generating example data? You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you produce an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, your posted exponential coefficients are imprecise (not enough places after the decimal point), and that magnifies  a lot when trying to regenerate the data.

Answer (score 0):

[`sklearn.metrics.auc`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) just estimates the integral for your given pair of `x` and `y` vectors using the [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). It doesn't make any strong assumptions about the functional form of the ROC curve.

In the second case you seem to have fitted an exponential parametric model to your data (in Excel?), then used [`scipy.integrate.quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) to integrate the fitted function over some interval.

There's no particular reason to expect these two approaches to give identical results. Without having the data there's no way for us to tell whether your exponential fit looks good, or even whether an exponential model is appropriate in this case.

Comment: you have properly interpreted my process, and yes i did use Excel. i'm using an exponential fit because that is how i modeled the data. i expected them to be equal because the definite integral equals the area under the curve...

Comment: In the second case you are *fitting* your data and then computing the integral from the fit, whereas in the first case you seem to be estimating the integral *directly* from the input data. At least that's my impression - it's unclear what you're actually doing since you haven't named your variables consistently, posted the full code, or provided any example input data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of your data, I get the following plots. For the path data (curr_path and then req_path), I use this function:

```
start = 8549826
def path(year):
    if year > 23: return start*(cur_path_exp)**23 * req_path_exp**(year-23)
    else: return start * (cur_path_exp)**year
```

and get this plot (over year from 1 to 61):
[image: Plot of the generated path data.]

For the sbt array, I use this function:

```
start = 8549826
sbt = lambda year: start * (sbt_exp)**year
```

and get this plot:

[image: sbt plot]

I then compared the integrals using `scipy.integrate.quad` and `sklearn.metrics.auc`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sklearn.metrics import auc
start = 8549826
sbt_exp = 0.9673405832388313
cur_path_exp = .9941
req_path_exp = 0.9522
sbt = lambda year: start * (sbt_exp)**year
def path(year):
    if year > 23: return start*(cur_path_exp)**23 * req_path_exp**(year-23)
    else: return start * (cur_path_exp)**year

years = range(1,62)
print "Quad sbt: ", quad(sbt, 1,61), "Auc sbt: ",auc(map(sbt, years), years)

print "Quad sbt: ",quad(path, 1, 61), "Auc sbt: ",auc(map(path, years),years)
```

and got the output:

```
Quad sbt:  (215108922.75692844, 2.3881887884705626e-06) Auc sbt:  154592534.468
Quad sbt:  (303985184.7185244, 0.4825437736101641) Auc sbt:  241740742.863
```

As you can see, they are quite different. This is because auc uses a simple trapezoidal rule, while quad uses the function you give it to interpolate the data and has a much higher level of accuracy. In summary, the difference between an **exponential** and a **piece-wise linear interpolation** is **huge**.

Comment: Thank very much for doing this! Your charts are correct What's throwing me off is that when I use 'auc' I get a less than 0.5% difference between 'sbt' and 'path'. When I take the definite integral, there is a 20% difference between 'sbt' and 'path'. Is the definite integral the more reliable calculation?

Comment: the main issue I'm trying to solve is to make the auc (or definite integral) of 'sbt' equal to cur_path + req_path. the cur_path equation is fixed, while the req_path equation is what i'm solving for. is it possible to get an equation for req_path given the auc (or definite integral) of 'sbt' and 'cur_path'?

Comment: Yes. You could write out the definite integrals and compute them symbolically,  with the req_path exponent as a parameter, then solve the equation. Or you could do a binary search on the exponent (probably easier).

Comment: scipy.quad is more accurate, if your data is actually exponential and continuous. Can you tell me exactly what the problem you're trying to solve is? Also, if my answer is helpful, you can thank me with an upvote :).

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is for the definite integrals of both equations to be the same. I need to figure out what the exponent in the `req_path` should be, or come up with a new equation for `req_path` all together. The `req_path` should still end at the same point as `sbt`.

Comment: Is there a way for python to solve for the `req_path` exponent? What is a binary search, and how do I do that? I tried to upvote you but I have less than 15 reputation. Sorry. Once I get more reputation, I'll come back and upvote you!

Comment: My bad, forgot you were 1 rep. I think I understand what you need now, and yes, Python can do it. You should ask a followup question (and give me the link), because comments aren't the place for answering questions, and your problem is different from your posted question.